# How to pass query sets from html to views.py in django using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, django

I am new to Django. So here, I am trying to pass a two query sets from Django html template to Django `views.py`. This has to happen on the click of a button and hence, I am using onClick function to pass the parameters to Ajax and from there, I am sending it to views. Here, along with the two query sets, I am passing two other values called rid and category and it is working fine, but the query sets are getting converted to string and hence I am not able to iterate through the query sets after passing it to the `views.py` page.

This is my `views.py` code:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    rid = request.POST.get('rid')
    category = request.POST.get('category') 
    extracted_records=request.POST.get('extracted_records')
    show_cards_records=request.POST.get('show_cards_records') 
    
    return render(request,'cards_update.html',{'extracted_records':extracted_records,'show_cards_records':show_cards_records,'rid':rid})

return render(request,'cardpage.html',{'extracted_records':extracted_records,'show_cards_records':show_cards_records,'rid':'1234'})
```

This is my main html code:

```html
<!-- templates/base.html -->
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>CardGame</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/cardpage.css"}>
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <h1>{{rid}}</h1>
            <div id='update_cards'>

            {% include 'cards_update.html' %}
            </div>
        </center>
    </body>

    <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type = "text/javascript" charset = "utf-8"></script>
    <script>
        function func(rid,category,extracted_records,show_cards_records) {
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Cardpage',
                data:{
                    'rid':rid,
                    'category':category,
                    'extracted_records':extracted_records,
                    'show_cards_records':show_cards_records,
                    
                },

                success: function (response) {
              
                    $("#update_cards").replaceWith(response);
                    alert("card casted.");
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

This is my page html code:

```html
<center>
    <button onclick="func('{{entry.rid}}','Rewards_And_Stipends','{{extracted_records}}','{{show_cards_records}}')"  type="button" class="submit-btn">REWARDS : {{entry.Rewards_And_Stipends}}</button>  
    <button onclick="func('{{entry.rid}}','Questions_Posted','{{extracted_records}}','{{show_cards_records}}')"  type="button" class="submit-btn">QUESTIONS POSTED : {{entry.Questions_Posted}}</button>
    <button onclick="func('{{entry.rid}}','Questions_Answered','{{extracted_records}}','{{show_cards_records}}')" type="button" class="submit-btn">QUESTIONS ANSWERED : {{entry.Questions_Answered}}</button>
    <button onclick="func('{{entry.rid}}','Quizzes_Played','{{extracted_records}}','{{show_cards_records}}')"  type="button" class="submit-btn">QUIZZES PLAYED : {{entry.Quizzes_Played}}</button>
    <button onclick="func('{{entry.rid}}','Mentorship','{{extracted_records}}','{{show_cards_records}}')"  type="button" class="submit-btn">MENTORSHIP : {{entry.Mentorship}}</button>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return HttpResponse in ajax case, and then handle in success at js.

```
if request.is_ajax():
    rid = request.POST.get('rid')
    category = request.POST.get('category') 
    extracted_records=request.POST.get('extracted_records')
    show_cards_records=request.POST.get('show_cards_records') 

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'extracted_records':extracted_records,'show_cards_records':show_cards_records,'rid':rid}), content_type='application/json')

return render(request,'cardpage.html',{'extracted_records':extracted_records,'show_cards_records':show_cards_records,'rid':'1234'})
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I am not able to send the query set from html to views and not from views to html

Comment: so you should check your urls.